# Docking Station not Detecting 2nd external Monitor

Tags: windows-10, laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have the following Setup which i can not get to work.

2 Monitors (same Size,  2560 x 1440 Pixels, I tried recuding the resolution to 1920*1080, which did not change anything) Connected to a Dell WD15 Docking Station using a `mini Displayport to DisplayPort` Cable and a `HDMI` Cable.

The dell WD15 is connected to my Notebook (Acer Aspire V Nitro (VN7-593G) with GeForce GTX 1060, Windows 10 latest, [detailed specs here](https://de-store.acer.com/aspire-v-15-nitro-vn7-593g-black-edition)) using the USB-C connector.

The Laptop only detects the Monitor connected using the HDMI Cable, the other one is not detected in the settings of the PC.

I tried to find out if the Bottleneck of my setup is the Docking station or the Laptop itself. But i could not find much Information which matches my Setup.

Is it possible to support two Monitors with my Laptop, or is it a general Problem of my Notebook and has nothing to do with docking Station and Configuration

Comment: Could you provide with the exact reference of the computer? Can't seem to find it with a GTX 1060

Comment: Do you have 60 Hz in *Settings > System > Display > Advanced display settings > Display adapter properties > Monitor > Monitor Settings > Screen refresh rate*? And what's the resolution of both monitors?

Comment: Also [the specs](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/AE/content/model/NX.G6JEM.034) say GeForce® GTX 960M with max Screen Resolution of 1920x1080, which is certainly not enough for two monitors.

Comment: @PoutchiPatch, I added the exact specs.

Comment: @harrymc. The Refresh rate is set to 60hz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of the problem is that you are connecting the dock to a USB-C
port, and therefore *you are not going through the GTX 1060*.
You are instead using a display adapter that is
*built into the dock*, which by its nature is a simple embedded adapter
of limited capability, not at all in the same league as the GTX 1060.

I found a firmware update for the WD15 Docking Station at the Dell page of
[Support for Dell Dock WD15](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/dell-dock-wd15/drivers).
You will find there a very recent firmware update from 23 Jan 2019.
There are a couple of other fixes for audio problems, which might also apply.

If that firmware update allows the mini Displayport to be detected, then the
problem might be solved.

If not, I suggest to avoid using the mini Displayport on the dock - use instead
the HDMI port that is on your computer.

Comment: Actually the Update does not work on a non Dell Computer, but connecting the 2nd Monitor over the Laptop HDMI Port does give me the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel>Power Options and edit your plan options for Laptop Lid Close action and see if it changes the behaviour when you are hot docking.